# LVM_GETITEMCOUNT working intermittently on VISTA

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-vista

There is SysListView32 control.I am trying to get the no of elements in ListView by using API

```
int iCount = SendMessage(hList,LVM_GETITEMCOUNT,0,0);
```

LVM_GETITEMCOUNT returns the no of items properly on XP.

But the same call working intermittently on VISTA. On Vista I am getting iCount =0;
GetLastError() on vista returns 0x05.Access denied.

How ever itemcount is returned while debugging since the process is launched with admin privileges

Any suggestios how to make this call work on VISTA?

Comment: You are getting access denied? Is the list in the process as the SendMessage call or external?

Comment: are you impersonating another user in the thread that send the message or the thread that owns the list control? Are you calling from another desktop?

Comment: Any chance that the hList is somehow invalid? Are you holding it for a long time, perhaps while the control is destroyed and re-created?